# Just wanted to know what's wrong with this question

Tags: discussion, specific-question

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11987264/how-to-add-arrow-to-border-of-block-on-hover

According to https://stackoverflow.com/faq#close it seems ok to me

Comment: If you're getting "what have you tried" comments, it's probably going to be NARQ because it doesn't show visible effort.

Comment: @simchona - But code is already pasted and what I want is clearly shown in picture

Comment: @simchona - Do people expect jsfiddle example each time?

Comment: No. We do, however, expect some effort.

Comment: @DaveNewton - OK then what do you think about this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10010116/how-to-create-an-arrow-in-css3?lq=1

Comment: @Jitendra Honestly, they are about the same in terms of quality. No idea why the other has so many upvotes...

Comment: @Jitendra Also, generally speaking, you should be able to edit your question, throw out there a few examples of what didn't work, then request your question be re-opened. If you add just a few of those details, you could certainly reverse the opinions of at least some of those down-voters.

Comment: @Jitendra I don't care for it, although I didn't look at the fiddle, which might or might not change my mind.

Comment: The fiddle, though not in the Question anymore was just an on hover with a blue border round the image. There was no experimentation other than showing a blindingly easy :hover example. I felt for Jitendra on the huge volume of negativity he got for his question as I for one would have actually appreciated a decent answer to it.

Answer (score 7):

While this case is sort of marginal, I think it's a "lack of effort" type of closure.  The relevant portion of the close reason is this (emphasis mine):

> This question is ambiguous, vague, ***incomplete***, overly broad, or rhetorical...

You have shown your code for the border, and a screenshot of what you would like to see, but *you haven't shown what you have tried so far to get from your code to the screenshot*.

A question being closed isn't the end of it, though.  If you have tried a few things (even if they didn't work), edit your post to add those in!  Explain your reasoning on what you attempted.  That alone would make it a good candidate for reopening (in my opinion).

---

As [Bart](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/161198/bart) points out [in the comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143734/just-wanted-to-know-whats-wrong-with-this-question#comment408982_143736), this type of question is also covered in the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) page (which is linked to from the Ask a Question page, and new users are required to read) under "Do your homework".  I personally think it's good practice to point users here when voting to close as "not a real question".

Comment: Agreed. And this partially boils down to the "Do your homework" part of the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) page linked in the FAQ.

Comment: @Bart Exactly!  I usually link to that when I vote to close a question like this as "not a real question"

Comment: @jadarnel - Then what do you say about this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10010116/how-to-create-an-arrow-in-css3 What effort has been made by OP to make arrow?

Comment: Also not great. But those questions that slip through the cracks are not evidence that you can ask a similar question. This one might have been missed.

Comment: @Jitendra A more productive use of your efforts would be to just take the advice linked to here (and the advice of the commenters on your question) and show your work so far (rather than trying to find counter examples).

Comment: @jadarnel27 - My last comments is about "Do your homework"

Comment: @Jitendra I know =)  I have nothing to add about the question you linked that Bart and Gaffi haven't already said.  I have voted to close that question as well (for great justice).

Comment: @Jitendra And you got a response to that comment.

Comment: @jadarnel27 ditto on the close (flag, not vote, for me).